# how get access to a password posted with a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that displays a password field and when the form is posted I call a javascript function during the page's onload -- and when I retrieve the password field it never has the password I entered, it's empty. Is calling a javascript function from onload the wrong approach here if I'm trying access the contents of the posted form?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPwd()
    {
        // okay the form was posted and we got called from onload, now get the post'd password
        var thePwd = document.getElementById("theUsersPassword").value;
        alert("the var thePwd is: " + thePwd);          
    }
</script>        
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Beta:</title>
</head>

<body onload="checkPwd()">

    <form method="post"  action="index.php">
    Beta: <input id="theUsersPassword" name="usersPassword" type="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you loading the same page when you submit the form?

Comment: Why do you want to access and check an `input type="password"` using JavaScript in first place? That puts doors open for security holes. Just submit the form to the server immediately and access it in `index.php`.

Comment: onload will be called when the page loads and not when the form is submitted.

Comment: @BalusC It can be relevant to read the password-input with JavaScript if you for instance want to make client side validation that the field isn't empty, prior to posting it to the server.

Comment: @Chris: OP seems not to be interested in validation (or perhaps he is not actually understanding what he is doing).

Comment: @BalusC True that, the purpose of the JavaScript is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the POST data fields from JavaScript.

What you do is that you block the real form submission and get the data from the form.

```
form.onsubmit = function () { checkPwd(); return false; };
```

Or if you're trying to do some kind of a validation, you need to return a boolean value from `checkPwd` and do `form.onsubmit = checkPwd`

Comment: I take it form.onsubmit is in javascript but where do I code the form.onsubmit stuff above?  In onload?

Comment: Somewhere after the `<form>` tag, you should place a `<script>` tag where you declare the `checkPwd` function and bind the `obsubmit` handler to the form.

Comment: Thanks dude that did me.  I will of course handle form input validation on the client side and password validation on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you don't want to check the input onload, you want to check it when the form submits right? Because at onload the user hasn't had the chance to enter anything yet.

If you want to do it onsubmit, just change your form tag to this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="checkPwd()">
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the element doesn't exist anymore.
Javascript only runs on one page, so if you do

```
document.getElementById('passwordform');
```

it won't find it because there is no element with that ID.
You could do it in javascript by storing the password in a cookie, or retrieving it via the LocalStorage api, but I'm not even going to show you how to do that, because it's unsafe.

Javascript is a client side language, so any code you write in it, is sent to the browser. This means that every user can view and manipulate your code.

You should do it with a server side language such as PHP.

In php, you can simply compare the value to the pasword you expect.

There are 2 ways to sent data from a form to the server: using the POST method, or using the GET method. The Get method is used for sending shorer pieces of information, and are appended to the url in the form of

```
example.com?variable=value
```

This is not a good idea for information that needs to be secure, and since a url has a maximum length (different for different browsers), so when you send password information, you should use the POST method.

So, your login form could look like this

```
<form action='securedpage.php'>
    <label>enter your password: <input type='password' name='pass'></label>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Now, in  securedpage.php, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$expected_pass="!4mr00t";
if($_POST['pass']===$expected_pass){
    //show your content
}els{
   //show homepage
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but isn't this normally done with PHP?

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['variable'])) {
   $first = $_POST['variable'];
   echo $first;
  }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="password" name="variable" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This code would spit out a password entered into a form.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: that's what my guess was.  I was wondering if my thinking is correct here: the form gets posted to the server, the server then provides a new blank form, so at onload time the password field is NOT the password field from the posted form -- it's an entirely new form created by the server when I post back into index.php and that's why the password is blank.  I need to get the post'd password BEFORE the server re-generates the form.  Correct?

Comment: hmm...are you looking to use it to validate the form?

Comment: I'm not that great at PHP, I just know the basics so maybe someone else could expound a little more on this.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks I'm new to web programming and I appreciate the help.  What I needed was the confirmation that php and not javascript is the right choice here -- if I need to access the entered password on the server.  I will use Javascript for input validation *prior* to the post -- thanks Christofer for that tip!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="return checkPwd()">
```

`checkPwd()` must return `false` to avoid the submission (If any problem) o `true` to perfom the action (If everythings is correct).

Comment: Cool thanks, that handles the input validation and blocking -- that is new to me, I did not know how to stop form submission when I discover invalid input -- thanks.

Comment: That could work, but it's not safe, or at least, the password should be validated on the server too.

Comment: @FrederikCreemers You're right, wantTheBest : You should never trust the client side 'validation'.